# How to display base64 file in react in cross browser fashion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, iframe, base64

Currently, I am getting a json file containing base64 encoded files. The types varies from pdf, docx, jpg, etc.

I have a look at different options:

They need physical files to feed into the component, in order to display.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-viewer

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-iframe

I have looked at iframe and anchor. It works in Chrome. IE and Firefox has security control so I cannot append data into iframe.src or a.href.

Also I heard that chrome has 3mb limit for base64 data

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[react-file-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-viewer) accepts dataUrl, so you can use base64 encoded files directly with it.